# FriendlyID history not working for updated model urls in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Following both FriendlyID's [wiki](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History) and [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) I've tried to rewrite and redirect my urls if the name of my user model has changed. Unfortunately nothings happening. I've ran the proper migrations:

```
rails generate friendly_id
rails generate migration add_slug_to_artists slug:string:uniq
rake db:migrate
```

And applied this code as instructed but to no avail. The url remains the same after initially creating the model instance.

**Artist Model**

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]
```

**Users Controller**

```
class ArtistssController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    if request.path != user_path(@artist)
      redirect_to @artist, :status => :moved_permanently
    end
  end

  def update
    if @artist.update_attributes(artist_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Artist successfully updated'
      redirect_to @artist
    else
      render 'edit'
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_artist
      @artist = Artist.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def artist_params
      params.require(:artist).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Comment: You didn't post the code for the `update` method so I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you need to set `slug` to `nil` in order for it to be regenerated.

Comment: @ViniciusPinto I've updated my question to show what's in the update action (default code generated from the scaffold). What would you recommend I do?

Comment: add `@artist.slug = nil` before the call to `update_attributes()`

Comment: @ViniciusPinto Does my answer accurately match what you're describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While its stated in their [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Slugged) the code for changing urls in your controller for FriendlyID 5 is never really explained. I ended up having to add `@artist.slug = nil` for this to take effect:

```
def update
  @artist.slug = nil
  if @artist.update_attributes(artist_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Artist successfully updated'
    redirect_to @artist
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: `@artist.slug = nil` should be before the call to `update_attributes`

Comment: Strangely enough when the `@artist.slug = nil` was in the conditional it was still able to rewrite the url. Wasn't sure of proper placement of the code which is why I wanted to clarify and ensure that this was done correctly. Regardless of the matter thanks for your help.